# Can Eclipse import a Maven Web project as a "Dynamic Web Application"?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jersey

**High Level Goal:** Create a single Maven Web Application project that can be used correctly in both Netbeans and Eclipse

When converting a Maven project to Eclipse, the project type doesn't seem to be set to Dynamic Web App when using the command: **mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0**

In Eclipse, if creating a Dynamic Web Application, many more options are shown in the Project Explorer, such as:  **JAX-WS Web Services, Deployment Descriptor, etc.**   It's a completely different framework structure.

[image]

Also, after converting to Eclipse with the above command, I can't "Run" it even though the output from the conversion says: [INFO] Using as WTP server : Apache Tomcat v7.0.  Instead of wanting to run as a web service, it asks me if this is Java Servlet, Applet, or Unit test.

[image]

With a Dynamic Web App (native Eclipse), this is what shows up when Running the project:

[image]

Maybe I am asking too much of Eclipse, and to get the built-in web app functionality, it can't come from Maven?

There is one other I could try.  I could create a Dynamic Web App in Eclipse, then hit "Convert to Maven" . Take that POM, modify, then see if netbeans will also load it.

**My 'pom.xml':**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.voxel</groupId>
<artifactId>servermap</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>userprofile</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-servlet-webserver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.18-m</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As suggested by jhericks ,if you use `m2eclipse` , you don't need to use `eclipse:eclipse goal`. What the `eclipse:eclipse goal` does can also be done by the m2eclipse.

To convert a project to the Dynamic Web Application , you can configure the `Project Facets` options in your project properties

[image]

Comment: This appears to be fundamentally what I was missing. The concept of project facets.  I still have a lot of work to do to tweak this to work on Eclipse + Netbeans + IntelliJ, but this gets me over the main problem I was having :)

Comment: Hmm... When I import my Maven module, this Project Facet automatically gets set for me, so I don't know what's different between me and @jsidlosky.

Comment: A step is missing: After adding the `Dynamic Web Module` facet, how to tell Eclipse to use `src/main/webapp` instead of its usual `WebContent` directory?

Comment: Answer to my subquestion: the directory to use for web content can be configured by clicking on "Further configuration available..."

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: this "Further configuration available" is not available for me. Maybe because of my version of Eclipse (Version: Indigo Service Release 2, Build id: 20120216-1857)?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: I was wrong! The "Further configuration available" option is actually available but only when you first add the Dynamic Web Module facet. Once you click OK and come back in Properties >> Project Facets, it won't appear!

Comment: @AdrienBe: Indeed! One has to be very careful to configure it at that time, because after clicking OK it is not possible to change it anymore.

Comment: That "further" setting does not disappear, but it goes in the "Deployment Assembly" settings table of the project under the / resource.

Answer (score 3):

I have had better luck with the [m2eclipse plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) from Sonatype.  When I started, I made the mistake of trying to use both m2eclipse and the eclipse:eclipse goal.  They don't do exactly the same thing, so if you install the plugin, stop doing mvn eclipse:eclipse.  Anyway, it has worked very well for me with single web projects and very well with multi-project reactor style projects as well.

The only problem I've had is with trying to deploy a war file to a server configured in eclipse if that war file is built with an overlay, but that doesn't seem to be an issue for you.

Comment: I used the m2eclipse plugin import method and it looks better than with mvn eclipse:eclipse method!  So thank you for that.  However, it's still not a "Dynamic Web App" from Eclipse's perspective.  I realize maybe I am asking too much, but I thought it might be possible.  I updated my post up top with screen-shots to make it more clear.  Thank you sir.

Comment: When I do it on my project it works.  I have the Run on Server option for my web applications (and it actually will launch it on my server).  I'm not sure what magic thing it's looking at in my project to make it work, though.  One thing you could try is to ensure that there is no .project file yet when you do the import.  Also, I can't tell from your screenshots but I assume you have a src/main/webapp/WEB-INF directory.  If not, that might be it.  One last thing to try - right-click on the project, choose Maven and then choose Update Project Configuration.  After that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I tried this and when doing "Run on server" I get `Document base /home/nico/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyWebapp does not exist or is not a readable directory`

Answer (score 2):

**m2e-wtp** plugin does this automatically, as stated here: [Import Existing Maven in Eclipse as WTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314750/import-existing-maven-in-eclipse-as-wtp)

All facets, source folders etc will be correctly set after import.

https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/