# Import Existing Maven in Eclipse as WTP

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I had to reinstall my Eclipse and now i have to import all the existing projects into the new workspace. The previous version of Eclipse was Galileo, this version is Indigo. The plugins are installed, but after the "Import Existing Maven Project" the projects are not showing as WTP (WebApp Project)...

Do i need something else to setup or config?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to install additional software. The "Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP"

See here: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/96737

Update Site: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/

Comment: But on this update site my Eclipse doesn't list this plugin... just this two: "m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse" and "m2e - slf4j over logback logging (optional)"

Comment: It's listed under m2e-extras. Try this:

http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras/

Not sure if the version fits though. I think Eclipse took the whole thing over from Sonatype, but maybe the extras still remain there.

Comment: I found it, but can't install because it's incomaptible with my installed Maven version...great :S

Comment: okay, i think i had some unnecessary maven plugin as well. after uninstall, the wtp plugin was installed correctly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a maven project to a Eclipse WTP project.
After that you only need to import the project as any other project.

The command to convert is:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```