# How to import a Maven+jetty project to Eclipse as a Dynamic Web Project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-wtp, maven-jetty-plugin

I have [a Maven project](https://bitbucket.org/mryoshio/neostruts2cmisexplorer) that uses Jetty ([pom](https://bitbucket.org/mryoshio/neostruts2cmisexplorer/raw/a8bee632a43d/pom.xml)), it can be run like this:

```
$ mvn jetty:run
```

Many developers want to debug it within Eclipse.

**QUESTION:** What is the most straightforward way to import the project into Eclipse in such a way that it can be debugged as a webapp?

---

**MY ATTEMPT:**

1. Run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` or `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=1.5`
2. In Eclipse, define the `M2_REPO` variable pointing to your Maven directory, for instance `/home/nico/.m2/repository`
3. Import > Existing project > Select the project directory > OK
4. Check "Dynamic Web Project" then click "Further configuration available..." and enter in "web content" enter "src/main/webapp". You can not change it afterwards.

I feel it is not far from working, but problem: I don't see how to tell Eclipse where the jars are.
Is there a better solution than copying all needed jars from the Maven repository to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` manually ?

Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6950103) is rather similar but the accepted answer is only a single step of the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install [Run Jetty Run](http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/)
2. Run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`
3. In Eclipse, define the `M2_REPO` variable pointing to your Maven directory, for instance `/home/nico/.m2/repository`
4. Import > Existing project > Select the project directory > OK
5. Right-click on project > Debug as > Run Jetty

Now the app will stop at your breakpoints, go step-by-step when you want, etc.